# Is there a way to use sumproduct (or something else) to subtract from inventory with a checkbox in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-macros

I've been racking my brain for the past week trying to figure out a way to create a semi-automatic inventory of my store in Google Sheets.

Currently I have one table where orders come in (automatically placed in). Each order gets 3 cells: `timestamp`, `order number` and `order info`. Timestamp and order number is self explanatory, order info is a comma-separated cell with what was purchased (for example: shirt, shirt, pants, shorts, shirt, shoes would be an order of 3 shirts, 1 pair of pants, 1 pair of shorts and a pair of shoes ) In addition I've added a true/false checkbox in column D.

[image]

On a second sheet I have what I'm calling my inventory. In this sheet, I have in the left-most column (column A) the names of each item. Next to that are columns for amount ordered in each month (each uses this craaaazy formula due to the way the timestamp comes in `=SUMPRODUCT(((INT((IFERROR(--MID('Inventory-Orders'!$A$2:$A,FIND("CREATED",UPPER('Inventory-Orders'!$A$2:$A))+LEN("CREATED"),10),0)-IFERROR(--RIGHT('Inventory-Orders'!$A$2:$A,5),0)))>=B$1)*(INT((IFERROR(--MID('Inventory-Orders'!$A$2:$A,FIND("CREATED",UPPER('Inventory-Orders'!$A$2:$A))+LEN("CREATED"),10),0)-IFERROR(--RIGHT('Inventory-Orders'!$A$2:$A,5),0)))<=EOMONTH(B$1,0)))*((LEN('Inventory-Orders'!$C$2:$C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((UPPER('Inventory-Orders'!$C$2:$C)),UPPER($A2),"")))/LEN($A2)))`
),

followed by a column of the total amount ordered (just a sum of the previous month columns) and one last column that is my remaining inventory.

Currently, I've been counting at the end of the week what I have left and updating it manually. I've been trying to figure out a way to combine the checkbox with that formula above to create an inventory that automatically subtracts the correct amount whenever I check the box in sheet 1 - Orders that marks it as fulfilled.

Nothing I seem to try works, I thought it would be a simple task, and it maybe that I'm overlooking something, so...is there a correct way to do this? I thought I could use the same function above with an IF statement but that doesn't get me anywhere good.

[image]

Comment: Is this Excel or google sheets?

Comment: It's Google Sheets.

Comment: It was just you had Excel tagged... but no longer.

Comment: Could you please share a sanitized copy of the spreadsheet you are working on? Also, would you be open to using Google Apps Script for this?

Comment: I would definitely be okay with using some type of Script. I thought that might end up being the way to go, but I'm rather new to that world.

Comment: [here is a sanitized copy, hopefully this works?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yMdNplUopEqTbsW6dmdqGAJokV0WlhenK8OzT17ypvs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Once you have developed a formula to automatically update the quantity purchased per month per item, wouldn't the remaining inventory be defined by the initial inventory minus all the quantities purchased each month? What's the point of having a checkbox?

Comment: Currently, an order comes in and it automatically updates the quantity purchased that month, but that's before the order has been fulfilled (by me). So if it subtracts before I fulfill the order, I see an inaccurate inventory for that moment. I'm looking to create something that's more accurate pre and post fulfillment.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it more (thanks to you, lamblichus!) maybe it makes more sense to add the checkbox and have it so it only counts in the quantity purchased per month after it's been fulfilled, then my inventory will be correct and I'll still only count on fulfilled. Is there an easy way to do this with the formula I've been using? I would think it would just need to add an IF statement but that also feels like it wouldn't be right because how can each cell be linked directly to the box next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only count the cells which have the checkbox next to it checked, you could add the `IF` condition for each element in `SUMPRODUCT`. Something like this:

```
IF('Labels-Standard Orders'!$D$2:$D, ((INT(...))))
```

For example, from your sample, in `C5` (June shorts) you could have this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF('Labels-Standard Orders'!$D$2:$D,((INT((IFERROR(--MID('Labels-Standard Orders'!$A$2:$A,FIND("CREATED",UPPER('Labels-Standard Orders'!$A$2:$A))+LEN("CREATED"),10),0)-IFERROR(--RIGHT('Labels-Standard Orders'!$A$2:$A,5),0)))>=C$1)*(INT((IFERROR(--MID('Labels-Standard Orders'!$A$2:$A,FIND("CREATED",UPPER('Labels-Standard Orders'!$A$2:$A))+LEN("CREATED"),10),0)-IFERROR(--RIGHT('Labels-Standard Orders'!$A$2:$A,5),0)))<=EOMONTH(C$1,0))))*((LEN('Labels-Standard Orders'!$C$2:$C)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE((UPPER('Labels-Standard Orders'!$C$2:$C)),UPPER($A5),"")))/LEN($A5)))`

#### Reference:

- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)